# Grouping a List of Objects into Threes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 100 items. I need to group them by 3.

```
record_1....      record_100
```

I need to somehow figure out a way to group 3 items together and send them to my print_form81l function and that will physically print it to a piece of paper (3 records per page)

```
for transaction in transactions:
     print_form_81l(transaction)



def print_form_81l(transaction): # I need to get 3 items from my list in here.
     record_1
     record_2
     record_3
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: And I'm confused as to what the function of `print_form_81l` is supposed to be. And what does `transactions` contain?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want but if you want to have nested sub lists of 3 elements from your list you can use list comprehension as follow:

```
new_list=[lst[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a sliding window of length n. Here, n is 3 now, if you wanna move the window by n steps every iteration use:

```
l = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6']

n = 3
for i in range(0, (len(l) - n + 1), n):
    print(l[i:i+n])

# output

['r1', 'r2', 'r3']
['r4', 'r5', 'r6']
```

If you wanna move the window 1 step at a time just modify the for loop:

```
l = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6']

n = 3
for i in range(len(l) - n + 1):
    print(l[i:i+n])

# output

['r1', 'r2', 'r3']
['r2', 'r3', 'r4']
['r3', 'r4', 'r5']
['r4', 'r5', 'r6']
```

`list comprehension` versions of the above 2 scenarios :

```
result1 = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, (len(l) - n + 1), n)]
result2 = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(len(l) - n + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer in the spirit of the one suggested by @Nk03, but with values being printed (it seems like that's what you want, though it's not clear from the question):

```
for i in range(0, len(transactions), 3):
    group = transactions[i:i+3]
    for transaction in group:
        print(transaction)
    print("\n")
```